# Compass configuration on a yeoman webapp project for a sub folder domain name

Tags: gruntjs, compass-sass, yeoman

I am deploying a yeoman web app project into a subfolder domain name ex. www.domain.com/subfolder

My problem is that with the default compass configuration on the grunt file i need to change those to the absolute path for httpImagesPath and httpGeneratedImagesPath so that images would correctly show up in production

```
compass: {
        options: {
            sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
            cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
            generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
            imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
            javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
            fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
            importPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components',
            httpImagesPath: 'http://www.domain.com/subfolder/images',
            httpGeneratedImagesPath: 'http://www.domain.com/subfolder/images/generated',
            httpFontsPath: '/styles/fonts',
            relativeAssets: false,
            assetCacheBuster: false
        },
        dist: {
            options: {
                generatedImagesDir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/generated'
            }
        },
        server: {
            options: {
                debugInfo: true
            }
        }
    }
```

So what happens is when I do grunt build my local images (sprite generated and image_url) will also have the absolute path.

What will be my configuration or workflow so that i have the production working and at the same time have my local dev working as well. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to set relativeAssets: true ?

Comment: @Stentor are you asking what happens if i set relativeAssets to true and httpImagesPath and httpGeneratedImagesPath still absolute?

Comment: @Stentor this happens to my css on .tmp/styles/main.css --> background-image: url('../../app/images/sunset-v2-ipad-portrait.jpg'); it makes it relative and adds /app instead of just /images --> this does not work, same thing happens on the dist

Comment: Can you show me your directory structure?